# jQuery returns 404 for valid rails route?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have this in my rails route:

```
scope '/api' do
    # ...
    resources :callbacks, only: [:create]
end
```

It *was* working (returning a 500 error) but I fixed that and suddenly I get a 404 error when this is run this bit of coffeescript:

```
  $('.add-callback button').on 'click', (e) ->
    $form = $(@).parent()

    $data =
      notes: $form.find('[name="callback-notes"]').val()
      date : $form.find('[name="callback-date"]').val()
      time : $form.find('[name="callback-time"]').val()

    $.ajax
      type: "POST",
      url: "/api/callbacks",
      data: $data,
      success: (data) ->
        if data.success
          $form.fadeOut ->
            location.reload true
```

and it returns this:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/callbacks 404 (Not Found)
```

But `POST /api/callbacks` is found in the list of valid routes when you get a 404 anywhere else:

```
callbacks_path   POST  /api/callbacks(.:format)  callbacks#create
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't included the obvious bit of information: What happens if you just type `http://localhost:3000/api/callbacks` into your browser address bar? In theory, I'd expect you to get an error because of using GET rather than POST, but if you get a 404 that would suggest an avenue of investigation... Or use `wget` or `curl` or similar to actually do a POST to it. It's ***extremely*** unlikely that jQuery is the issue here.

Comment: Returns a 404 due to it being a GET request. But I included the line in the 'valid routes' bit of the 404 page that states the above should be valid. I tried `CuRL` but I get `Invalid authenticity token`

Answer (score 1):

I am utterly stupid. I found the answer using this bit of code in the console:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST', 
  url:'/api/callbacks', 
  complete:function(xhr){ document.body.innerHTML=xhr.responseText; }
})
```

The route was valid but it sent a 404 because a record I was trying to access inside the controller wasn't found.